# How to capture mouse wheel (Middle Button) click event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, mouseevent, mousewheel

I want to know how to capture mouse wheel click event which shows:

[image]

Following image I want to capture the event of auto scroll down/up on moving mouse, to right left top bottom buttons respectively. On moving my mouse below, above, to left or right of that image (Navigation image)

Comment: Not all OS'es let you scroll with the middle mouse click. So I doubt that there'll be a native way to find that. You could use the `onscroll` event after a middle mouse click, but you can't be certain about *how* they scroll.

Comment: I think using the `onscroll` event should be sufficient. I don't know your exact circumstances, but i can't think of any good reason to have different behaviour depending on `how` your user scrolls. consistent behaviour should be more user-friendly.